# Sharing part of structure for one platform while blacking it out for other

Tags: c++, c, structure, cross-platform, bit

I am working on a piece of code which has some structure with bit-fields where one of its member needs to be used for one platform and blacked out for other. Example:

```
struct FooBar
{
    int iFoo: 1, <----------------- Used only for platform 'X'
        iBar: 1, <----------------- Used on platforms 'X' and Y''
        unused: 2; <--------------- Would change to 2 or 3 based of platform
};
```

One simple and straight forward solution would be to use ifdef macro. But it would not look clean and is not a good engineering approach. **I want the structure to be cross-platform. Is there a way to do so without using ifdef inside structure?**

I tried `#define SIZEFOO 0` for platform X and replacing bit-field with this macro, but it complains about zero bit-field width.

Comment: Polymorphism? `struct FooBarX : FooBar {};`

Comment: I think people need more information about what it is you're trying to achieve to give you a good answer. There's not enough detail here.

Comment: [tag:c] or [tag:c++]...? BTW as far as I can understand, you have different struct for different platform: this is not cross-platform struct: it is per-platform struct

Comment: This is a huge structure and is nested inside a union inside a structure. The code is huge and being used at a lot of places. I don't intend to make all clients using it.

Comment: @LPs: Being used in both C and C++. I would like to keep it for C

Comment: beware of modifying the definition of a type, it's hard to avoid ODR violations if you do, whatever you are trying to achieve would probably be best served in platform specific usage of the data. However if you really do need divergent definitions have you tried zero sized arrays?
Template specialisation would be fairly clean but you'd lose C compatibility.

Comment: As stated at the moment, only chance is to use #ifdef linked to specific platform macros. Maybe changing includes that define that specific type.

Comment: @TheSombreroKid: I was aware that zero sized arrays can be used when it comes when we have series of data. Can it be used for bit-field?

Comment: @LPs: ifdef is fine as long as we use it outside structure

Comment: @Greengoblin What I meant is to re-define the bitfield variable per-platform, using #ifdef to select which one to use.

Comment: @LPs: This is giving zero field width error when the field is `#define` for one platform

Comment: Note that you can give an anonymous bit field size of `: 0` but it has a special meaning (allocate further bits in the next storage unit).  You can't create a named bit field of size 0.

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to keep it for C" - going with my comment: let's emulate polymorphism then:

```
struct FooBar
{
   // only the variables common to ALL structs
};

struct FooBarX
{
   struct FooBar common;
   // specific variables here
};
```

If you make the common FooBar always the first member, you can safely cast between `FooBar*` and `FooBarX*`, as address of the struct and address of the first member always are the same. Important: This only applies for C, though! C++ is different in this respect: In C++, this only applies for [standard layout types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout) – however, this is the case here...

Comment: You wont be able to preserve the bitfield this way

Comment: @TheSombreroKid That is true - but I'm not too sure if using a bitfield in such cases is a very good idea anyway. As long as all bits are of size 1, no problem, but if sizes get larger, it might get difficult to maintain the correct ranges (`int x : 10; int y: 12; int z : 20;`).

Comment: The code must be future proof. The changes I am making would be used in decades to come.

Comment: @TheSombreroKid One could use two bitfields, though: common one in FooBar, specific ones in FooBarX.

Comment: @Greengoblin if this code needs to be future proof then this is definitely completely the wrong way to go about it, any solution is brittle and will fall apart without extreme care.

Comment: @Greengoblin Then drop the bitfields!!! C and C++ standard both only define that fields defined one after the other must be adjacent, but the order in which the bits are filled in (MSB first or LSB first) is *implemtation defined*. Compiler might decide to change from one version to the other, and future safety is gone!

Comment: @Greengoblin And you should set alignment explicitly (e. g. `pragma pack(push 4)` + `pragma pack(pop)`), as default alignment from one compiler (version) to the next might vary or it might have been changed via compiler flags.

Comment: We have alignment being set explicitly. I am working on piece of code that has been in production for decades. It would be difficult to drop the bit-fields

Comment: @Greengoblin Are you aware that - if you drop one field - be it with ifdef or not - that the other fields will move within the underlying type? E. g. bit index of ibar won't be the same for platform X and Y.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The thing is iFoo didn't exist before. I have to bring it in shared structure and use it for platform 'X'. Make sense?

Comment: I personally would prefer not to touch the original bit field... Then, we'd be back at my original solution, though: You could start a new bitfield within FooBarX...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use pre-processor macro inside your struct

```
#define PLATFORM_X
struct FooBar
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_X
    int iFoo: 1, <----------------- Used only for platform 'X'
#endif
    int iBar: 1, <----------------- Used on platforms 'X' and Y''
    int unused: 2; <--------------- Would change to 2 or 3 based of platform
};
```

You can use different headers that defines specific struct per-platform

```
#define PLATFORM_X

#ifdef PLATFORM_X
   #include "platform_x_bitfiled.h"
#endif
```

where `platform_x_bitfiled.h` will be

```
struct FooBar
{
    int iFoo: 1, <----------------- Used only for platform 'X'
    int iBar: 1, <----------------- Used on platforms 'X' and Y''
    int unused: 2; <--------------- Would change to 2 or 3 based of platform
};
```

Comment: Why not show the `2` as `XY_UNUSED_SIZE` with `#ifdef PLATFORM_X` / `#define XY_UNUSED_SIZE 2` / `#else` / `#define XY_UNUSED_SIZE 3` / `#endif`, or something approximately equivalent to that?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 'cause the frist approach ii is not acceptable for OP, and the second one is designed to have a specific header with specific struc, so why bother with macros?

Comment: OK; you're trying to reconcile the irreconcilable.  "I want it to be the same on all platforms, except that it must be different on different platforms, and I don't want to make it different in the portable way so I will insist on doing it some other how".  Apologies — the OP needs their expectations adjusted.

Answer (score -1):

See @JonathanLeffler's comment, this doesn't work, the comments are ignored.
<s>This is the best i've got, it's not very good tbh and it's ODR violation potential is high but it's probably something like what you're after?</s>

https://godbolt.org/g/7d29wT

```
#define PLATFORM_X
#ifdef PLATFORM_X
#define PX_REMOVE //
#define PY_REMOVE
#elif defined(PLATFORM_Y)
#define PX_REMOVE 
#define PY_REMOVE //
#endif

struct FooBar
{
    int PX_REMOVE iFoo: 1, 
    PY_REMOVE iBar: 1, 
    unused: 2;
};
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int main() {

}
```

How about this?

https://godbolt.org/g/1zJ0s4

```
#define PLATFORM_Y
#ifdef PLATFORM_X
#define PX_REMOVE(value)
#define PY_REMOVE(value) value,
#elif defined(PLATFORM_Y)
#define PX_REMOVE(value) value, 
#define PY_REMOVE(value)
#endif

struct FooBar
{
    int PX_REMOVE(iFoo: 1) 
    PY_REMOVE(iBar: 1) 
    unused: 2;
};
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int main() {

FooBar f;
f.iBar = 1;
}
```

Comment: This is freaking genius :) I think it would solve my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Please be so kind to post the code here, too: 1.: This is good practice on SO anyway. 2.: I personally cannot see the code - it shows me just the square sample...

Comment: We can have macro like DONT_USE_FOO. But yeah, won't be that clean

Comment: Plus, we need to have another macro to take care of ``unused

Comment: @Greengoblin Would `int : 0;` help? This fills the rest of the underlying type, such that the next field starts with a new int...

Comment: Why would you name unused bitfields, all the bits after unused are also unused. If it's to preserve ordering @Aconcagua is right, bitfield formats are not preservable between compilations.

i.e. putting a structure like this anywhere other than main memory is a recipe for disaster. if it goes in a file or a socket, or anywhere else there's no guarantee it'll be readable when coming back out.

Comment: This is not a modern code. I am not sure if we needed unused filed long back. These days, we don't need to explicitly specify. As per all discussion, commenting out macro seems to be of very less risky and easily done, although I am not in favor of including it in struct

Comment: The `#define PX_REMOVE //` notation is identical to `#define PX_REMOVE` — the C preprocessor removes the comment (replaces it with a blank) before it tokenizes the line to process the `#define`.  This could only work if the C preprocessor was stuck in C90 mode and unaware of `//` comments, yet the main C compiler was aware of `//` comments.  That's a broken setup.  This is, therefore, not an effective solution — it is a non-solution.